# DataGrip - sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target

Tags: datagrip

I'm receiving this error while opening MS SQL database tables in DataGrip.

Other solutions  to the problem where related to updating Java codes but mine was related to DataGrip accessing MS SQL DB.

Answer (score 2):

Solution was to update DataGrip to latest build.
I need to run several times **Help - Check for updates** and than Restart in **Event log** - or probably restarting manually should work as well.

Unless you see "You already have latest version..." when hitting Help - Check for updates than you should update again.

In my case I had to update 3 times from one build to another until reaching last one, at the time of writing `2022.1.5`

This could happen when you update your DB server to latest security release and don't update DataGrip.

Comment: It's better to use [JetBrains Toolbox App](https://www.jetbrains.com/toolbox-app/) for updates